# HTACCESS redirect to folder based on hostname

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, hosting

I have multiple websites under the same web server.

My root structure is as following:

./

./site1/

./site2/

./.htaccess

I would like htaccess file to redirect to the correct folder.

If the user navigates to www.site1.com or site1.com it should rewrite the url to go to the ./site1/ folder and if the user navigates to www.site2.com or site2.com it should rewrite the url to go to the ./site2/ folder.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is suggested you should do this requirement in apache config file. .htaccess should be use inside your folder for project specific activities.Try to add folder path in document path of host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^site1/ /site1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^site2/ /site2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```